# How can I create a moving average with customizable symbol input?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to create my own moving average indicator where you can adjust the symbol input.

Because with the prefabricated MAs it is so that you can not change the symbol, but the MA automatically takes the symbol of the chart.

Therefore I would like to create a MA script that makes it possible, for example, if I have the chart of SPX open, to put the MA of IWM on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the request.security function
[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request{dot}security](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity)

Example:

```
IVM_MA = request.security("IVM", timeframe.period, ta.sma(close, 14))
```